# What is the Laplacian Matrix used for?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, graph-laplacian

You can turn graphs into several matrix forms depending on what data you want to focus on.  Does the Laplacian form have any uses on its own, or does it need to be paired with other things as some intermediary to be of use?

just wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Laplacian form of the graph is the basis for a family of clustering techniques named [Spectral Clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_clustering). The idea is to get the principal components of the matrix as representants for "most connected" regions.